# libGDX FressType font misses accented characters (french)

Tags: libgdx, freetype

I'm learning to create a game with libGDX and uses a FreeType font.
When I try to display "déplacer", I get "dplacer" (missing "é")

here is how I get the font :

```
 public static BitmapFont getFont(String file, int size){
        FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal(file));
        FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
        FreeTypeFontGenerator.setMaxTextureSize(2048);
        parameter.size = size;
        BitmapFont font = generator.generateFont(parameter);
        generator.dispose();
        return font;
    }
```

the font file is the "arial.ttf" windows font

here is how I use the font : 1st create a label style in the skin

```
private void setTitleLabelStyle(){
    Label.LabelStyle lbs = new Label.LabelStyle();
    lbs.font = Assets.getFont("arial", 150);
    lbs.fontColor = Color.WHITE;
    game.uiSkin.add("title", lbs);
}
```

and then

```
    setTitleLabelStyle();
    Label label = new Label(title, game.uiSkin, "title");
    panel.add(label);
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm stupid !!!
the problem came from the file in which I read the texts: it was coded in ANSI, not in UTF-8 !!!
I'm sorry for asking a useless question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm stupid !!!
the problem came from the file in which I read the texts: it was coded in ANSI, not in UTF-8 !!!
I'm sorry for asking a useless question

Answer (score 0):

A bit chaotic, but with no info about the text content, something like:

```
parameter.characters += "€«»ÀàÂâÆæÇçÉéÈèÊêËëÎîÏïÔôŒœÙùÛûÜüŸÿ";
```

Or:

```
byte[] b = new byte[256 - 160];
for (int i = 160; i < 256; ++i) {
    b[i - 160] = i;
}
parameter.characters += new String(b, "ISO-8859-1");
```

Tip: the following tests a java.awt.Font for unavailable characters:

```
String text = "déplacer"; // Or parameter.characters.
Font font = ...;
int errorIndex = font.canDisplayUpto(text);
if (errorIndex != -1) {
   System.out.println("Font cannot display " + text.charAt(errorIndex));
}
```

Comment: thanks for this very quick answer... but neither first nor second solution work
and I was unable to use the tip => "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/Font"... sorry

Comment: I tried : generator.generateData(parameter).hasGlyph('é') before disposing generator.
It returns TRUE, so it seems that there is a glyph for character 'é'

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, and the solution. One learns